# How to select radio button by default in a list which may appear any how depending on the onload dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, odoo-9

I want to select the value of a radio button by default on change of the value of another radio button. Let's say a list contains 10 values as a whole. But if I set checked="checked" in the input tag, the default value gets selected but when the dependency is loaded, nono of values in the list varies. So the default value gets hidden at the back end. And no default value is selected.

The scenario will be clearer with the pics shown below.

**In image 1:**  none of pins have in total 15 values and default value selected is 050. And when the value of the center of distance changes nome of pins also changes. So I want default value selected in that too.

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

Please help with this issue.

Comment: show some code here which you tried

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets say class of the div "center distance" is center-distance and class for div "Numbers of pins" is "number-pins"

```
//On change event of the radio buttons inside "center-distance" div
$(".center-distance input:radio").on("change",function(){
    //Functionality will go here after selection of radio button inside div with class "center-distance"

    //Make select first radio button which is not hidden inside div with class "number-pins" 
    $(".number-pins  input:radio:visible:first").eq(0).prop("checked", true).trigger("click"); 
});
```

Comment: I have shared above code as per assumption as such you haven't shared your html in the question.. you can made change in the code as per your html.. ane please accept the answer if it will help you.